# Mac System storage taking up too much space

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, storage, jenkins

Recently on my Mac Pro I installed Jenkins as I am trying to make it as our Build Machine for building our iOS app.

And now intermittently the system keeps taking up enormous amounts of space, above 150 GB's of my 250 GB SSD.

Any idea of what might be taking up so much space and also any way to find the culprit here?

Comment: "the system"? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You've not given us much to go on, but it's probably Time Machine local backups, at `/.MobileBackups`

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin you were right it was Time Machine Backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the app DaisyDisk from the Mac Appstore and run it on your disk. This app produces a graphical map showing how the space on you disk is being used. This makes it very easy to spot and identify large files and folders. The app is $10 but they have a free trial version which has limited capabilities. A similar app, [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net), is free.

Comment: Thanks for this. It showed me the culprit as @Tetsujin pointed out it was a Time Machine Backup.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this issue on my Mac, which was suffering from approx 300GB of system storage on a 500GB SSD, leaving me only 30GB.
I pinned it down to Time Machine, which apparently now stores a 'snapshot' of your backup-set locally, and the issue may also have had something to do with my backup drive failing.
So I deleted the failed backup drive from Time Machine, disabled backups, then ran the following commands in Terminal to delete all the local snapshots, which you have to do one-by-one after you have got a list of all the relevant dates/codes:

1. tmutil  listlocalsnapshotdates
2. tmutil deletelocalsnapshots YYYY-DD-MM-HHMMSS

Following this, I freed up about 220GB of System storage.

Hope that helps! I'm not at all technical, and just stumbled across this after combining threads from different posts.